# Looping through find output in Bash where file name contains white spaces

Tags: bash, find, while-loop

I try to search for files that may contain white spaces I try to use `-print0` and set `IFS` here is my script

```bsh
IFS=$'\0';find people -name '*.svg' -print0 | while read file; do
    grep '<image' $file > /dev/null && echo $file | tee -a embeded_images.txt;
done
```

I try to fine all svg file containing embeded images, it work without -print0 but fail one one file so I stop the script. Here is simpler example that don't work too

```bsh
IFS=$'\0';find . -print0 | while read file; do echo $file; done
```

it don't display anything.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `read -d '' -r file` and set `IFS` only for the context of `read`:

```
find people -name '*.svg' -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do
    grep '<image' "$file" > /dev/null && echo "$file" | tee -a embeded_images.txt;
done
```

And quote your variables.

Comment: The @IFS= read@ approach succeeds on files ending with spaces

Comment: Strange `read -d'' -r file; do` don't work but with space `-d ''` does.

Comment: @jcubic: The content of the single quotes is null. Bash sees `-d''` as one argument. When it does quote removal there's nothing left but `-d`. It sees `-d ''` as _two_ arguments, one of which is null.

Answer (score 29):

Though [Dennis Williamson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11366230/1426891) is absolutely correct, it [creates a subshell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13726764/1426891), which will prevent you from setting any variables inside the loop. You may consider using process substitution, as so:

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do
    grep '<image' "$file" > /dev/null && echo "$file" | tee -a embeded_images.txt
done < <(find people -name '*.svg' -print0)
```

The first `<` indicates that you're reading from a file, and the `<(find...)` is replaced by a filename (usually a handle to a pipe) that returns the output from `find` directly. Because `while` reads from a file instead of a pipe, your loop can set variables that are accessible from outside the scope.