# how do I loop through the results of this FIND command in my Linux shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I wrote the following command to list all files in and below '~' by order of file size.  It seems to work fine:

```
find ~ -printf "%k KB %p\n" | sort -nr
```

Now I want to put this is a shell script and loop through the results to do more processing.

I got this to work with a simple 'ls' command:

```
dir="/home/myusername"
cmd='ls'
for i in `$cmd`
do
  echo $i
done
```

But this doesn't work:

```
dir="/home/myusername"
cmd='find $dir -printf "%k KB %p\n" | sort -nr'
for i in `$cmd`
do
  echo $i
done
```

I've also tried using escape characters in front of the double-quotes, but that didn't work either ...

```
dir="/home/myusername"
cmd='find $dir -printf \"%k KB %p\n\" | sort -nr'
for i in `$cmd`
do
  echo $i
done
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @BroSlow hi -- thanks for the help, but that was a typo in my question -- I changed the "~" to "$dir" -- thx

Comment: No problem, also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11366230/3076724 to fix your `find` syntax, otherwise it will break on spaces/weird characters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [find while loop with files containing spaces in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366184/find-while-loop-with-files-containing-spaces-in-bash)

Comment: @thatotherguy thanks, but I don't think it's the same issue.  I'm just trying to run the admitted tricky command and the escape characters aren't working

Comment: @RobertHume The escape characters aren't working because your approach is fundamentally flawed. To loop over results, use the linked question's method (and `sort -z` to sort).

Comment: Part of the problem is that you're trying to put the command in a variable before executing it, and that'll fail when the command contains anything nontrivial (in this case, quotes and a pipe). See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 3):

Try this while loop with find in BASH:

```
while read -r f; do
    echo "$f"
done < <(find "$dir" -printf "%k KB %p\n" | sort -nr)
```

Answer (score 1):

To execute simple commands, you can pipe the results of `find` into `xargs`:

```
find ~ -printf "%k KB %p\n" | sort -nr | xargs -l -i echo '{}'
```

`-l`: makes `xargs` process one line at a time.

`-i`: substitutes each occurrence of `{}` with the output of the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11366230/3076724 for an explanation of why not to use original syntax)

```
find "$dir" -printf "%k KB %p\n" | sort -nr |  while read -r i; do
  echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: @RobertHume You're definitely running it as a bash script?

Comment: I think so -- how can I be 100% certain?

Comment: @RobertHume Put `ps -o cmd= -p $$` inside the script. Or just `echo $0 `from your shell before you run it to see what shell you're using, or just run it as `bash whateverscript`

Comment: Isn't the default delimiter of `while read` syntax a newline character?