# Bash recursively find files with special characters in the name

Tags: bash, msys

I have the following function to recursively find files, yet it does not work when there are spaces in the file names. What am I doing wrong here?

```
for f in "$(find "$1" -type f -name '*.*')"
do
  echo "Processing $f file..."
done
```

Comment: It looks like your question has an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11366184/1426891); I have a slight improvement that I'll post there as well. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @JeffBowman, I couldn't find that question at my first search..

Answer (score 0):

You have to tweak the IFS variable, as space is taken as a separator by default.

All explanations and different solutions can be found here.
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/handling-filenames-with-spaces-in-bash.html