# How to make this (l)unix script dynamically accept directory name in for-loop?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, for-loop, terminal

I am teaching myself more (l)unix skills and wanted to see if I could begin to write a program that will eventually read all .gz files and expand them. However, I want it to be super dynamic.

```
    #!/bin/bash

dir=~/derp/herp/path/goes/here

for file in $(find dir -name '*gz')
    do 
       echo $file
    done
```

So when I excute this file, I simply go

`bash derp.sh`.

I don't like this. I feel the script is too brittle. 
How can I rework my for loop so that I can say

```
bash derp.sh ~/derp/herp/path/goes/here (1)
```

I tried re-coding it as follows:

```
for file in $*
```

However, I don't want to have to type in bash

```
derp.sh ~/derp/herp/path/goes/here/*.gz.
```

How could I rewrite this so I could simply type what is in (1)? I feel I must be missing something simple?

### Note

I tried

`for file in $*/*.gz` and that obviously did not work. I appreciate your assistance, my sources have been a wrox unix text, carpentry v5, and man files. Unfortunately, I haven't found anything that will what I want.

Thanks, 
GeekyOmega

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for dir in "$@"
do
    for file in "$dir"/*.gz
    do 
       echo $file
    done
done
```

Notes:

- In the outer loop, `dir` is assigned successively to each argument given on the command line.  The special form `"$@"` is used so that the directory names that contain spaces will be processed correctly.
- The inner loop runs over each `.gz` file in the given directory.  By placing `$dir` in double-quotes, the loop will work correctly even if the directory name contains spaces.  This form will also work correctly if the `gz` file names have spaces.

Comment: I definitely gave you rep for this reply. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $(find "$@" -name '*.gz')
do 
   echo $file
done
```

You'll probably prefer `"$@"` instead of `$*`; if you were to have spaces in filenames, like with a directory named `My Documents` and a directory named `Music`, `$*` would *effectively* expand into:

```
find My Documents Music -name '*.gz'
```

where "$@" would expand into:

```
find "My Documents" "Music" -name '*.gz'
```

Requisite note: Using `for file in $(find ...)` is generally regarded as a bad practice, because it does tend to break if you have spaces or newlines in your directory structure. Using nested for loops (as in John's answer) is often a better idea, or using `find -print0` and `read` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11366230/1426891).

Comment: @John1024: You beat me to the punch! That addition is already in my editing window. :)

Comment: Thank you both John and Jeff. I learned a lot from this question! You both rock. I feel inspired to keep studying and also to measure the merits of both approaches. Thank you.