# Transfer a path with space in bash

Tags: bash, quotes

I'm trying to run a program on every file on a dir.
But there is spaces in the name of the file.  For example, a file can be named «/my/good/path/MY - AWFUL, FILE.DOC»
And when I'm trying to send the path to my the other tool (a python script), I've got an error saying «MY» is not a existing file. :(

Here is my current bash code:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

for file in $(find "/my/pash" -name "*.DOC")
do
    newvar=`program "$file"`
done
```

So… where is my problem?

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Are all of the documents in the same directory, or are they in subdirectories too?

Comment: They are in subdirectories.  Like «my/path/sub1/MY FILE WITH - SPACES, AND, COMMAS.DOC»

Comment: Would it be sufficient to do `find '/my/path' -name '*.DOC' -exec script.py {} \;`?

Comment: How many questions are there that this is a duplicate of?

Comment: What do you do with the string captured in `newvar`?  Must you process one file at a time, or can `program` process multiple files in a single invocation?  If you don't need the output and `program` only handles single files, then @TomFenech's suggestion is good.  If `program` handles multiple files, then use `find "/my/pash" -name "*.DOC" -exec program {} +` with a `+` in place of the `\;` behaves more or less like `xargs`, running the program with convenient numbers of files.

Comment: Please consider using the `$(command)` vs `\`command\`` form of [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)

Answer (score 2):

Some correct answers, but no explanations so far:

a `for` loop is intended to iterate over **words** not lines. The given (unquoted) string is subject to [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) (which is what is troubling you) and [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion), and then you iterate over the resulting words. You could set IFS to contain only a newline. The safest way is to use `find -print0` and `xargs -0` as demonstrated by [Vytenis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29449676/7552)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

find "/my/pash" -name "*.DOC" | while read file; do
  newvar="$(program "$file")"
done
```

Note that this only fixes the case where a space or tab is in the file name. If you have a newline in the file name, it gets [a little more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11366230/836738).

Answer (score 1):

```
find -name "*.DOC" -print0 | xargs -r -0 -n1 program
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because the for loop will take every *word* inside the result of the find as an element to iterate over. `for` will see it as:

```
for file in {/my/good/path/MY, -, AWFUL, FILE.DOC}
    echo "$file"
done
```

And will print:

```
/my/good/path/MY
-
AWFUL,
FILE.DOC
```

One solution to this problem is to use the `xargs` program to pass the result of the `find` as your python program argument:

```
find "/my/pash" -name "*.DOC" -print0 | xargs -0 -i program "{}"
```

Comment: I think it is better to add `-print0` option to find, no?

Answer (score 0):

the loop treats blanks as delimiter, so try this one:

```
find "/my/pash" -name "*.DOC" | while read file; do 
   newvar=`program "$file"`
done
```